# MySqlCommands c#

Tags: c#, mysql

Why doesn't my `INSERT` command work? There is no error but my data is not being stored in the database:

```
    private void Button_Login(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Connection ConnectClass = new Connection();
        ConnectClass.Connect.Open();
        string mailcheck = @"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?";
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(Mail.Text, mailcheck))
        {
            Warnings.Content = "Error: Please enter a valid email!";
        } 
        else if (Password.Text == "" || Password.Text.Length > 32 || Password.Text.Length < 6)
        {
            Warnings.Content = "Error: Password must be at least 6 and not more than 32 characters!";
        } 
        else if(Password.Text != CheckPassword.Text)
        {
            Warnings.Content = "Error: Passwords do not match!";
        } 
        else
        {
            MySqlCommand success = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `accounts` (`mail`, `password`) VALUES ('test', 'test')", ConnectClass.Connect);

            Window1 Register = new Window1();
            Register.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("You have successfully registered!","Register");

            ConnectClass.Connect.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should [read the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html), which will tell you how to use MySqlCommand correctly.

Comment: `Why don't work command?` - The age old question I ask myself every day. I suspect it doesn't work because you create the command and never execute it.

Comment: Please, 1/. Do not store password in plain text. 2/. Use proper query parameter. 3/. Use System.Net.Mail.MailAddress to validate Email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `ExecuteNonQuery()`:

```
MySqlCommand myCommand= new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `accounts` (`mail`, `password`) VALUES ('test', 'test')", ConnectClass.Connect);
myCommand.Connection.Open();
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
myConnection.Close();
```

As an aside, please don't store plain text passwords. Use a salted, hashed password. Also, do not concatenate text (it's vulnerable to SQL injection), use parameterised queries instead.

Ref.: [The MySqlCommand Object](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html)

Comment: would the downvoter please leave a comment...